# Transition applying when element added , not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i was working on a small transition effect , where the background color of div changes every 4's , the problem is that , the bg color changes with a transition only when **adding** the bg color and not **removing** the bg color  :

The HTML ::

```
<div class="test-it" id="test-it">
    HELLO
</div>
```

THE CSS ::

```
.test-it {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.red {
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

and the JS code ::

```
(function() {

    var apollo = {};

    apollo.hasClass = function(elem, className) {
        return elem.classList.contains(className);
    };

    apollo.addClass = function(elem, className) {
        elem.classList.add(className);
    };

    apollo.removeClass = function(elem, className) {
        elem.classList.remove(className);
    };

    apollo.toggleClass = function(elem, className) {
        elem.classList.toggle(className);
    };

    window.apollo = apollo;

})();

apollo.addClass(document.body, 'test');

apollo.addClass(document.getElementById('test-it'), 'red');

var $str = apollo.hasClass(document.getElementById('test-it'), 'red');


var run = function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        apollo.toggleClass(document.getElementById('test-it'), 'red');
        setTimeout(function() {
            run();
        }, 2000);

    }, 2000);

}

run();

console.log($str);
```

Don't really look into the JS code much , as the error or desired behavior needs to be in CSS , so can somebody explain why is it that the transition is not applied when the class `.red` is taken off ??

the class .red has the following CSS ::

```
.red {
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

so why is the 2 second transition not applicable when when the class is taken off ??

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply your transitions to the main element, because once you remove the `.red` class, the transitions are no longer part of the element, thus, no transitions.

So your CSS should look like this

```
.test-it {
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                background: #eee;
                line-height: 200px;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: verdana;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
                -webkit-transition: 2s;
                -o-transition: 2s;
                transition: 2s;
            }
            .red {
                background: red;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks ! i had tried that and that had worked , but i wanted to know `why` ? thanks for the explanation !

Comment: No problem! Also keep in mind though, that just setting the transition as broadly as that will transition _every_ property, if you only want to transition the background color use `transition: background-color 2s`

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark as the answer if you feel that this answered your question :)